# Kivy, ScreenManager sizing issue

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a game for Android using Kivy. The idea is, for now, to have the main menu, then buttons to navigate.
(i.e. Screen size needs to be 9:16)

---

At first, I designed the entire main menu, (location of buttons, etc), and everything was perfect.

**However, to move on I had to start using 'ScreenManager'. Once I did, all the buttons and sizes were extremely wrong and huge.**

Upon further inspection, I realized that this only occurs when changing "class MainMenu(**Widget**):" to "class MainMenu(**Screen**)", I don't know why or how this would make such a big difference, and the fix is.

I will try to provide screenshots to help further explain what I mean.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Py Before:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '900')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1600')    


class MainMenu(Widget):
    pass


class BackGardenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


BackGardenApp().run()
```

Kv Before:

```
<MainMenu>:
    name: "MainMenu"
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'Background.Jpg'
            size: root.width, root.height

    Label:
        bold: 'true'
        font_name: 'Misty Cotton.ttf'
        font_size : root.width * 0.25
        center_x : root.width / 2
        top: root.top * .92
        text: "Back"
    Label:
        bold: 'true'
        font_name: 'Misty Cotton.ttf'
        font_size : root.width * 0.25
        center_x : root.width / 2
        top: root.top * .75
        text: "Garden"

    Button:
        text: "Play"
        font_name: 'font3.ttf'
        font_size: root.width * .06
        size: root.width*.8 + 100, root.height*0.1
        background_normal: 'ButtonLong.png'
        background_down: 'ButtonLongPressed.png'
        pos: ((root.width/2)-((root.width*.8 + 100)/2)), root.height * 0.18

    Button:
        text: "Settings"
        font_name: 'font3.ttf'
        font_size: root.width * .06
        size: root.width*.4, root.height*0.1
        background_normal: 'Button.png'
        background_down: 'ButtonPressed.png'
        pos: root.width*0.5 + 50, root.height * 0.0625

    Button:
        text: "Shop"
        font_name: 'font3.ttf'
        font_size: root.width * .06
        size: root.width*.4, root.height*0.1
        background_normal: 'Button.png'
        background_down: 'ButtonPressed.png'
        pos: root.width*0.1 - 50, root.height * 0.0625
```

Py After:

```
from kivy.app import App
# from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

width = 900
height = 1600


def screensize():
    Window.size = (width, height)


class LoadingIn(Screen):
    screensize()
    pass


class MainMenu(Screen):
    screensize()
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screensize()
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("BackGarden.kv")


class BackGardenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BackGardenApp().run()
```

Kv After:
(Numbers are percentages as it allowed it to be available at any window size.)

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    LoadingIn:
    MainMenu:

<LoadingIn>
    name: "Loading"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "MainMenu"

<MainMenu>:
    name: "MainMenu"
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'background.jpg'
            size: root.width, root.height

    Label:
        id: logo1
        bold: 'true'
        font_name: 'Misty Cotton.ttf'
        font_size : (root.width * 0.35)
        center_x : root.width / 2
        top: root.top * .90
        text: "Back"
    Label:
        id: logo2
        bold: 'true'
        font_name: 'Misty Cotton.ttf'
        font_size : (root.width * 0.35)
        center_x : root.width / 2
        top: root.top * .75
        text: "Garden"

    Button:
        text: "Play"
        font_name: 'font3.ttf'
        font_size: root.width * .06
        size: root.width*.8 + 100, root.height*0.1
        background_normal: 'ButtonLong.png'
        background_down: 'ButtonLongPressed.png'
        pos: ((root.width/2)-((root.width*.8 + 100)/2)), root.height * 0.18

    Button:
        text: "Settings"
        font_name: 'font3.ttf'
        font_size: root.width * .06
        size: root.width*.4, root.height*0.1
        background_normal: 'Button.png'
        background_down: 'ButtonPressed.png'
        pos: root.width*0.5 + 50, root.height * 0.0625

    Button:
        text: "Shop"
        font_name: 'font3.ttf'
        font_size: root.width * .06
        size: root.width*.1, root.height*0.1
        background_normal: 'Button.png'
        background_down: 'ButtonPressed.png'
        pos: root.width*0.1 - 50, root.height * 0.0625
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to `Screen` class recognizing things like `size_hint` while the `Widget` class does not. So the `Shop` button size will be defined by its `size_hint` rather than its `size`. Try changing  `size: root.width*.1, root.height*0.1` to `size_hint: 0.1, 0.1`, and similar for the other Buttons.

Comment: @JohnAnderson and this is why I love this website :)
It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is due to Screen class recognizing things like size_hint while the Widget class does not. So the Shop button size will be defined by its size_hint rather than its size. Try changing size: root.width*.1, root.height*0.1 to size_hint: 0.1, 0.1, and similar for the other Buttons.